# "Absolute Positioned" Item shifting layout vertically

Tags: html, css, position

I recently figured out how to vertically align an item using the absolute position, and it worked perfectly fine until I did something to it today. I was reworking my layout so that it would be fluid and work at different screen resolutions, and now the item is shifting up and over existing layout items, extending far outside it's containing div (Is there a way to keep that from happening?). I know it's doing this because it's "Absolute positioned" which I've read removes it from the flow of the website, but is there a way to keep this item within it's contained div? It's moving up because when the screen shrinks the contents get squished together and it pushes everything up.

This is driving me especially crazy because I'm pretty sure it was working perfectly fine before, even with the resizing, and I think I messed with something and ruined it. How do I make this absolute position thing behave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the positioning of the item's parent element to be `relative`. Absolutely positioned elements are only relative to their nearest absolutely or relatively positioned parent.

However, there's probably a better way to achieve the vertical alignment you're going for than using absolute positioning...

Comment: The parent element is already set to relative, I had to fight with that to get it to work. Do you have suggestions as to other ways to vertically position something on the bottom?

Comment: Could you post an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: here is a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/tcfnvtvq/) to what I'm basically trying to do.  I don't understand why data2 and data3 aren't floating as they should, because they do in my own code, but my main issue is getting data1 (and the img if possible) to sit at the bottom of the TD without using absolute position, as neither height is set and it keeps messing up my layout. @embden

Comment: Vertical alignment won't work when combined with floating, but you can use absolute positioning if the parent element (the <td>) is relatively positioned. Since you want to position the content to the bottom, use `bottom:0;`. See updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ganskop/tcfnvtvq/1/

For data2 and data3, you're missing the number sign before them in the CSS selectors - they should be referenced as #data2 and #data3.

Note that generally it's preferred not to layout content with tables, but in your particular use case, it might work fine.

Comment: I've already gotten the absolute position thing to work, but then I noticed that when I resized my screen, as I have a fluid layout, the content in Data1 (or the img next to it) would suddenly be too tall for it's container, and it'd break out, since it's removed from the flow of the layout. This is what I want to avoid. And I can't set the container height because it's dynamic content, so I need an alignment solution other than absolute positioning. I updated the jsfiddle to show you [link](http://jsfiddle.net/tcfnvtvq/2/)

Comment: Ok, then I think your best bet is to add cells to the table so the elements are in their own cells, and then just use `vertical-align:bottom` (without floating): http://jsfiddle.net/ganskop/tcfnvtvq/3/

Answer (score 0):

You could try playing with the z-index property, but it depends on your layout

Comment: That might help the item show up in front of the navigation bar it's blocking, but I want it to not break through it's containing div at all. I don't understand why it isn't doing that anyway. Why doesn't the whole layout just move down the page like normal?

Comment: absolute wont move down like normal, post your html+css if you want better answers

Comment: Thanks, but I've decided to live with not having my items aligned on the bottom like I'd want. The items don't have set heights, so I can't design around the fact that absolute position is removed from the flow of the layout, and no one seems to have other ideas that work for vertically aligning things on the bottom of an element. oh well.